# How to query rows having only alphanumeric values in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a table with row name "bill_no".
I wan't to make laravel query to fetch only those rows which have column bill_no as alphanumeric(Q 68) or just numeric(1307).

[image]

It would be a great great help if you can suggest me something.

Comment: use a where clause.

Comment: What should I place inside the where clause that is more of my question.By the way thank you for responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its strange of me answering my own question but one way which I used to solve this problem is by using REGEX.
To get all bill having **numeric value** I used -

```
->where('bill_no', 'regexp', '^[0-9]')
```

To get all bill having **alphanumeric value** I used -

```
->where('bill_no', 'regexp', '^[A-Z]')
```